# ASP.NET MVC 2: Breaking changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, migration

**What will be broken after migrate to MVC 2?**

---

I wonder what breaking changes will come with MVC 2, so how traumatic will be the migration?

How much smooth have been your experience migrating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The release notes have the breaking changes: [ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM Release Notes](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=46&SrcFamilyId=C9BA1FE1-3BA8-439A-9E21-DEF90A8615A9&SrcDisplayLang=en&u=http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/B/1/7B11DE4E-0247-448E-8D39-7C9B12ABA1FF/ASP.NET-MVC-2-RTM-Release-Notes.doc)

I had no problem upgrading, just some issue with registering Castle Windsor IoC container... only had to change the signature though:

[Migrate from .NET MVC 1 to MVC 2 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004850/migrate-from-net-mvc-1-to-mvc-2-rc)